# How do I apply my helper module function to every element in my array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, function, helper

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I apply my helper function, taht takes one parameter, to every element of an array?  I have this array

```
arr = ["ele1", "ele2", ...]
```

And I have a method that reads, "MyModule.my_function(arg)", which I wish to apply to every element of the array.  But trying the below results in an error.

```
2.4.0 :005 > arr.map(&MyModule.my_function)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr.map(&MyModule.my_function)
```

tries to call `MyModule.my_function` without argument, which gives you the error message above.

You could just use :

```
arr.map{ |x| MyModule.my_function(x) }
```

or

```
arr.map( &MyModule.method(:my_function) )
```